# FindException: Module name not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Screen shot]

I'm working on a Java project named "airbnbapi" which uses the Java module system and JavaFX. I have configured my project to use the module system, set the module name to "airbnbapi", and added the necessary module dependencies in my module-info.java file. However, when I try to run my project, I get a "java.lang.module.FindException: Module airbnbapi not found" error.

I have tried multiple solutions including setting the module path in the run configuration, ensuring my project is located in the root directory, and double-checking my module-info.java file for errors. However, I still can't seem to get my project to run properly.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

I have tried creating a Java module named airbnbapi with the required dependencies json, javafx.base, javafx.fxml, javafx.controls, and javafx.graphics. I have also configured my project structure such that the com.example.airbnbapi package containing all the classes and the hello-view.fxml file are located under src/main/java and src/main/resources respectively.

Despite these attempts, I am still encountering a ModuleNotFoundError with the message java.lang.module.FindException: Module airbnbapi not found.

I have also tried setting the module path in my IDE and specifying the module name as airbnbapi in the module-info.java file. Additionally, I have checked that the module name is consistent across all files and directories.

However, the error persists, and I am unable to run the program successfully.

Here are my Run/Debug configurations:

[image: Configuration]

Comment: the module name (that is the part after _module_ and the opening bracket) seems to be com.example.airbnbapi (not airbnbapi). btw: no screenshots of plain text - such as module-info and the error message - instead, c&p!